# Login APIs Google automático

Tags: java, python, google-maps, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-app-engine

Vuelvo una vez más con una nueva duda, estoy desarrollando una aplicación que tira de varias APIs de Google. Mi problema es el login, que quisiera que sea fijo.

Os explico un poco más en detalle, actualmente conozco dos formas diferentes para autorizar a una aplicación a usar los servicios de Google para un usuario determinado:

1. Autorización vía Web a través de un código, el usuario inicia sesión en Google, después autoriza los scopes, lo cual le saca un código que ha de insertar en mi app.
2. Autorización vía Web, el usuario necesita iniciar sesión y autorizar mi aplicación, con este paso me salto el que tenga que introducir un código.

Una vez detallados esos dos casos, los cuales están genial para cuando el usuario no es fijo, quisiera saber si existe la forma de que el login sea a través de una cuenta fija sin tener que hacer que un usuario se logee de forma manual en dicha cuenta.

La respuesta podría ser en Python (el lenguaje con el que estoy desarrollando esta app) o java.

Gracias de antemano

Saludos

EDIT: estoy usando las [Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/quickstart/python)

Comment: Miguel: Por un lado, no deben forzar etiquetas en el título (referencia: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging), por otro, en este sitio lo que que se usa es aceptar respuestas y votar arriba o votar abajo (referencia: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), no deberían agregarse comentarios como "Gracias" o "Solucionado" ni en el título ni el cuerpo de la pregunta así como tampoco en los comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la opción de cuenta de servicio. Los detalles se indican en https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

### Extracto original

> #### Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications
>
> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions
>   such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this
>   scenario you need a *service account*, which is an account that belongs
>   to your application instead of to an individual end user.

### Traducción

> #### Uso de OAuth 2.0 para aplicaciones de servidor a servidor
>
> El sistema Google OAuth 2.0 soporta las interacciones de servidor a servidor
>   como las que existen entre una aplicación web y un servicio de Google. Para 
>   esto se necesita una *cuenta de servicio*, que es una cuenta que pertenece
>   a su aplicación en lugar de a un usuario final individual.

Comment: Muchas gracias, a primera vista diría que es justo la solución a mi problema. Me estudio el enlace que me has puesto y os cuento que tal

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente, me he rallado tratando de conseguir que la cuenta de servicio pudiera realizar las operaciones correctamente (subir ficheros Drive), pero una vez que la he dado permisos a sido fácil.

Answer (score 0):

No se si he entendido bien tu pregunta, pero si quieres poder logearte en una cuenta de Google para poder acceder a servivios que lo requieran como ver el correo, mediante código Python un método sensillo es parsear la página de login para obtener los `imput` de usuario (`Email`) y contraseña (`'Passwd'`), agregar ambos datos y luego enviarlo para autentificarnos. Usando [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) que permite la persitencia de cookies de sesión, [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) para parsear el html y en `Python3.x` puede quedar algo así:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class SesionGoogle():
    def __init__(self, email, contraseña):
        self.sesion = requests.session()

        url_login = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin"
        url_aut = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth"

        login_html = self.sesion.get(url_login)
        soup_login = BeautifulSoup(login_html.content, 'html.parser').find('form').find_all('input')
        datos = {u['name']:u['value'] for u in soup_login if u.has_attr('value')}
        datos['Email'] = email
        datos['Passwd'] = contraseña
        self.sesion.post(url_aut, data = datos)

    def get(self, URL):
        return self.sesion.get(URL).text
```

Para crear una sesión solo hay que instanciar la clase y pasarle nuestro usuario(correo) y la contraseña. Hecho esto podemos usar nuestra instancia  para ingresar a páginas que requieran estar logeados, por ejemplo podemos acceder a la bandeja de entrada de nuestro correo como se muestra a continuación:

```
mySesion = SesionGoogle("miUsuario@gmail.com", "miContraseña")
print(mySesion.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"))
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no me vale.quisiera que el login automático me permitiera obtener las credenciales para poder llamar a las APIs del Drive y Sheet, para subir ficheros y actualizar unas hojas de calculo, pero no quiero que el usuario pase por el navegador.