# Error is not JSON serializable con Python y OAuth 2.0 Client ID API de Google

Tags: python, google-oauth

Este es mi código de Python + OAuth 2.0 Client ID API:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from urllib import request
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import json
import requests

client_id='xxxxxxx.googleusercontent.com'
client_secret='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

query = 'site:xxxxxxxxx.com intitle:"linux"  "vulnerability"'

dir_api='https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/vi?key='
url=dir_api+client_secret+"&cx="+client_id+"&q="+urllib.parse.quote(query)

resultado = requests.get(url)
print( json.dumps(resultado.json, indent=4) )
```

El error que muestra es :

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <bound method Response.json of <Response [404]>> is not JSON serializable
```

No puedo encontrar información sobre el tema.
Tengo instalado requests

Comment: Conozco muy poco de python, pero atrevo a decir que el código no está completo. ¿Tu código es un [mcve]?

Comment: El error 404 significa que no existe el recurso que buscas. O sea está mal tu URL.

Comment: Relacionado: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37098/login-apis-google-autom%C3%A1tico?rq=1

Comment: Tu error es que `resultado.json` en la linea del print es una funcion, pero debes llamarla, y para eso se añade un `()` al final, quedando así: `resultado.json()`